# my activemq plugin not work

Tags: plugins, activemq-classic

I write an ActiveMQ plugin, but it does not work.

### The code:

```
package cn.ennwifi.mqttplugin;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.Broker;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerPlugin;

public class MqttPlugin implements BrokerPlugin {

  public Broker installPlugin(Broker broker) throws Exception {
    return new MqttFilter(broker);
  }

}


package cn.ennwifi.mqttplugin;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.Broker;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.ConnectionContext;
import org.apache.activemq.command.ConnectionInfo;

public class MqttFilter extends BrokerFilter {
  public MqttFilter(Broker broker) {
    super(broker);
    System.out.println("mqtt插件");
  }

  @Override
  public void addConnection(ConnectionContext context, ConnectionInfo info) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("mqtt连接信息：" + info.getClientId());
    if (info.getUserName() != "123") {
      return;
    }
    super.addConnection(context, info);
  }
}
```

---

### The configure:

---

```
<plugins>
       <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" id="myplugin" class="cn.ennwifi.mqttplugin.MqttPlugin"/>
    </plugins>
```

I used mvn:clean package pack a jar,put it to activemq/lib
The version is 5.14.1

Comment: Could you please edit your question to add the code. That would make it a lot easier for anyone trying to answer.

Comment: I have added the code

Answer (score 0):

I change my code

```
if (info.getUserName() == null) {
      throw new Exception("用户名不能为空");
    }
```

I used throw an exception replace return.

Answer (score 0):

Use Log4j to be able to see what's happening.

Do something like below:

```
private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MqttFilter.class);

LOG.info("my message");
```

Hope this helps.